# Is there a driver for 138a:00ab Validity Sensors, Inc. fingerprint reader?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, fingerprint

I just got a new computer that comes with this device

```
> lsusb -s 003 -v

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:00ab Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
```

and the closest to some positive thing about this working I found is [this](https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/138a:00ab), at least I'd think if anything is certified it's working :)

I'm running Ubuntu 18.

Any ideas where I might find a driver for this?

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no Linux driver for this device.

You can keep an eye on it on these two links:

- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/issues/118
- https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90/issues/50

Comment: Doesn't seem very active unfortunately :(